Python using use_scm_version keyword in setuptools setup()
I am using setuptools.setup() function inside my setup.py:
setup(use_scm_version={"version_scheme": get_main_version, "local_scheme": get_local_version})

The use_scm_version keyword has configuration parameters "version_scheme" and "local_scheme" (following the setuptools_scm docs)
Each pointing to a function callable in my setup.py:
def get_main_version(version: ScmVersion) -> str:
    return "0.0.1.dev0" # set build version to always return 0.0.1.dev0

def get_local_version(version):
    return get_local_node_and_date(version)

Notice get_main_version() returns "0.0.1.dev0", so that my builds should always be versioned 0.0.1 regardless of the scm system.
However the version_scheme callable is not executed, and my wheel is labeled v0.0.2 following setuptools_scm's automatic git versioning system.
$ python -m build
* Creating venv isolated environment...
* Installing packages in isolated environment... (setuptools>=64, setuptools_scm>=8)
* Getting build dependencies for sdist...
...
...
Successfully built my_package_name-0.0.2.dev1+ge361241.tar.gz and my_package_name-0.0.2.dev1+ge361241-py3-none-any.whl

Why is get_main_version() not being called?
My pyproject.toml has the same configuration as the docs:
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools>=64", "setuptools_scm>=8"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

